# Meteor publish composite not return anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I tring meteor tabular so i created meteor publish composite but didn't get users value in console

this is my code:

```js
Meteor.publishComposite 'admin_images_tabular', (table_name, ids, fields) ->
    find: ->
      denyNonAdmins @userId
      self = @
      q = 
        _id:
          $in: ids
      return Photos.find(q)
    children: [{ 
          find: (photo) ->
            console.log 'photo::', photo
            console.log 'photo user_id::', photo?.user_id
            _.each photo?.participants, (participants) ->
              console.log 'participants::', participants
              user_cursor = Meteor.users.find({_id: participants?.user_id})
              console.log 'users::', user_cursor.fetch()
              user_cursor
    }]
```